# Sourcetree branch is not showing on the sidebar

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

[Sourcetree no branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjVPF.png)

I want to compare the difference between branches but sourcetree has no branches on the sidebar, how can I solve this?

Comment: Use CTRL (Windows and Linux) and choose any two commits you like in log view. It does not matter what branch the commits belong to.

Comment: Thanks Jay. This answers my question!